# Errors occur when compiling tensorflow serving by bazel: Python Configuration Error: --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH='/usr/bin/python3' is not executable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was installing the tf serving by compiling the source code.
The command line was:

```
$ git clone -b r1.10 https://github.com/tensorflow/serving.git
$ cd serving
$ bazel test tensorflow_serving/...
```

and my bazel vision is

```
$ bazel --version
bazel 2.1.0
```

The error information is as follows:

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_python':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_limingliang/1c00e8fe288c428416b8275600af1770/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 345
        _create_local_python_repository(<1 more arguments>)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_limingliang/1c00e8fe288c428416b8275600af1770/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 292, in _create_local_python_repository
        _check_python_bin(<2 more arguments>)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_limingliang/1c00e8fe288c428416b8275600af1770/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 234, in _check_python_bin
        _fail(<1 more arguments>)
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_limingliang/1c00e8fe288c428416b8275600af1770/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 27, in _fail
        fail(<1 more arguments>)
Python Configuration Error: --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH='/usr/bin/python3' is not executable. Is it the python binary?
```

I find that in the "/usr/bin/" directory, there is not the python3 bin file.

```
$ cd /usr/bin/
$ ls | grep python
python
python-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
pythonw
pythonw2.7
```

So I change the value of PYTHON_BIN_PATH to "/usr/bin/python"

```
$ export PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python
$ echo $PYTHON_BIN_PATH
/usr/bin/python
```

However, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is defining the python path as '/usr/bin/python3', so adding /usr/bin/python' to the path may not matter. Have you tried linking /usr/bin/python3 to /usr/bin/python?

For example, ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

Comment: ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

In the terminal you can use the link command (ln) to create a symbolic link (-s) from one path to another, so if the builder is trying to us 'python', but your system is set to use 'python3', then the link allows either command to call the same python files.